# Is Lubuntu the same as to Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, server, lubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 server (headless) and I need to migrate all applications and data to Lubuntu (it's a customer's requirement). I have a lot of Ubuntu applications installed and managed (databases (PostgreSQL), development tools (1C) and lots of configured first party stuff (apache, samba) for this version of Ubuntu.

Will all of them work as fine in Lubuntu as in Ubuntu after migration?

Comment: If you are using a headless server in the true sense of the word, you will have to connect a graphical monitor, mouse and keyboard to the system... ;-)

Comment: It wont make a single bit of difference: ubuntu server does not use a desktop and it is the desktop that makes it lUbuntu.

Comment: Why are you running a desktop OS on a server?

Comment: i run server os on server, but i have a task to set it up on desktop for a user, who can use only gui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they will work fine, with Lubuntu the only different is the desktop environment which is LXDE, you still have access to all main repositories and softwares thus you will feel no change.

Ubuntu flavors are using a same base while they are optimized to act as best as they can with the desired desktop environment.

From lubuntu.net:

> The core of the system is based on Linux and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu **Server** is a distro *without any* GUI (or “headless”). Both Ubuntu **Desktop** and Lubuntu are equally far from Ubuntu Server, despite the name suggesting that Ubuntu Desktop is more similar to Ubuntu Server.

Actually, there are several GUIs you can use:

- Unity in Ubuntu **Desktop**
- KDE in Kubuntu
- XFCE in Xubuntu
- LXDE in Lubuntu
- and a lot of others (with variously named distros)

So by moving from Ubuntu Server to Lubuntu (i.e. adding LXDE to your GUI-less system), you will get a GUI and won’t lose anything.

Comment: also MATE in ubutnu mate ,BUDGIE in Budgie Ubuntu

Comment: @SMITPATIL Of course, I mentioned those with names formed in the same way as for Lubuntu.